# How to convert elements of a list from string to integer in Python?

Tags: python, integer, int

I have to do a multiplication of matrix, but I have to give the elements row by row. I know I have to write them as a string, but I do not know to convert them into a int/integer.

```
for i in range (0,orden):
    b= input("Write the numbers of the row, of the first matrix")
    a.append(b)
    ar.append(a)
    a=[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use `int(s)` to convert string to integer.